# How to load a text in R in Quanteda

Tags: quanteda

I am completely new to the whole text mining process and I only discovered Quanteda one day ago. I cannot even start exploring its tools because I seriously cannot understand how to load a text. I just can't.
I want to mine whole scientific studies that I have them in PDF format and what I do, is to copy the study's main text into my TextEdit on my Mac and then save it as an .XML document.
From that point on,  I don't see how to proceed. Please, any help would save me. I have stuck here for hours. As you see from the files panel, I want to load this document that is called small.xml, but it doesn't seem to be working. Any idea?

[see this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8cvm.png)

Comment: Importing files into "the computer" is probably one of the hardest problems in text analysis, so don't feel too discouraged!

You're on the right track but your particular XML file might take a bit more work than just relying on `readtext()` (although this often does work).
Can you supply a link to the actual XML file?

Comment: There is no link to provide. I just had a a study in PDF. so far so good. I copied a small portion of the text (1-2) paragraphs into a word document and then I saved this document as "small".xml  as you see above. I did this because I read in the readtext() info that the function reads predominantly .xml documents. As you see above, it won`t work